# Upcoming Salesforce server split, know the new server in advance?

Tags: split

Salesforce has notified us that our NA4 server will be splitting on March 21, 2015. Is there any way to know in advance what Salesforce server our production instance will live on after the split?

Comment: Have you asked Salesforce support?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I followed Girbot's suggestion and opened a case with Salesforce Support. Within two days they provided the server name that my Org will be migrated to.

Answer (score 0):

I received 2 emails about this on Feb 24 within about 30 mins of each other. On first glance they looked identical, but the 2nd one actually said which instance it was moving to. Might be worth taking a second look at your inbox.